# How to create a OTP layout in android compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I was making a login for my app in the new android jetpack's compose.

I want to make a OTP layout like in the given photo.

[image: OTP Layout]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a very simple layout for each char in the otp.

Something like

```
   @Composable
   fun OtpChar(){
       var text by remember { mutableStateOf("1") }
       val maxChar = 1

       Column(Modifier.background(DarkGray),
              horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally){
           TextField(
               value =text,
               onValueChange = {if (it.length <= maxChar) text = it},
               modifier = Modifier.width(50.dp),
               singleLine = true,
               textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
                   fontSize = 20.sp, 
                   textAlign= TextAlign.Center),
               colors= TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                   textColor = White,
                   backgroundColor = Transparent,
                   unfocusedIndicatorColor = Transparent,
                   focusedIndicatorColor = Transparent)
           )
           Divider(Modifier
                    .width(28.dp)
                    .padding(bottom = 2.dp)
                    .offset(y=-10.dp), 
             color = White,
             thickness = 1.dp)
       }
   }
```

[image]

You can add some features like:

- manage the focus in Next direction with the TAB key
- manage the focus in Previous direction with the BACK SPACE key
- how to move to the next textfield when a digit is entered

Something like:

```
fun OtpChar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    val pattern = remember { Regex("^[^\\t]*\$") } //to not accept the tab key as value
    var (text,setText) = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val maxChar = 1
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    LaunchedEffect(
        key1 = text,
    ) {
        if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
            focusManager.moveFocus(
                focusDirection = FocusDirection.Next,
            )
        }
    }

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ){
        TextField(
            value =text,
            onValueChange = {
                if (it.length <= maxChar &&
                    ((it.isEmpty() || it.matches(pattern))))
                        setText(it)
            },
            modifier = modifier
                .width(50.dp)
                .onKeyEvent {
                    if (it.key == Key.Tab) {
                        focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next)
                        true
                    }
                    if (text.isEmpty() && it.key == Key.Backspace) {
                        focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Previous)
                    }
                    false
                },
            textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                textAlign= TextAlign.Center),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                imeAction = ImeAction.Next
            ),
            colors= TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Transparent,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Transparent),

        )
        Divider(
            Modifier
                .width(28.dp)
                .padding(bottom = 2.dp)
                .offset(y = -10.dp),
            color = Teal200,
            thickness = 1.dp)
    }
}
```

Then just use something like a `Row` to display 4 `OtpChar`s

```
val (item1, item2, item3, item4) = FocusRequester.createRefs()

Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween){
    OtpChar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(item1)
            .focusProperties {
                next = item2
                previous = item1
            }
    )
    OtpChar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(item2)
            .focusProperties {
                next = item3
                previous = item1
            }
    )
    OtpChar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(item3)
            .focusProperties {
                next = item4
                previous = item2
            }
    )
    OtpChar(
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(item4)
            .focusProperties {
                previous = item3
                next = item4
            }
    )

    //....
}
```

[image]

Comment: I need this layout for the very purpose of receiving users' OTP done via Firebase Auth. The snippet of code you provided me has the following problems: It is vertical and whenever I enter the second character it changes line. Secondly, The Divider does not appear on every single character of text. Thirdly, the line must show at the place before even I entered the text. Thank you for taking your time to help me.

Comment: @GautamHazarika this snippet is just for a single char. I have updated the answer, adding also the code to define a max number of characters (in this case 1) for each TextField.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti pls explain how to move to the next textfield when a digit is entered.

Comment: When I did this and I focus the next TextField, the keyboard jumps because it gets closed, reopened, and then it becomes numeric. Is there a way to make this less jarring

Comment: @lalitjadhav updated the answer with the focus manager

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti if I type rapidly some clicks getting ignored. if i type 1590 its getting type 190 only.

Comment: How can I get string combined from all OtpChar?

Answer (score 8):

check full example [here](https://gist.github.com/alphadotwork/c0f1963ab92d8926640f4c405155a402)

```
const val PIN_VIEW_TYPE_UNDERLINE = 0
const val PIN_VIEW_TYPE_BORDER = 1

@Composable
fun PinView(
    pinText: String,
    onPinTextChange: (String) -> Unit,
    digitColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground,
    digitSize: TextUnit = 16.sp,
    containerSize: Dp = digitSize.value.dp * 2,
    digitCount: Int = 4,
    type: Int = PIN_VIEW_TYPE_UNDERLINE,
) {
    BasicTextField(value = pinText,
        onValueChange = onPinTextChange,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
        decorationBox = {
            Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
                repeat(digitCount) { index ->
                    DigitView(index, pinText, digitColor, digitSize, containerSize, type = type)
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
                }
            }
        })
}


@Composable
private fun DigitView(
    index: Int,
    pinText: String,
    digitColor: Color,
    digitSize: TextUnit,
    containerSize: Dp,
    type: Int = PIN_VIEW_TYPE_UNDERLINE,
) {
    val modifier = if (type == PIN_VIEW_TYPE_BORDER) {
        Modifier
            .width(containerSize)
            .border(
                width = 1.dp,
                color = digitColor,
                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium
            )
            .padding(bottom = 3.dp)
    } else Modifier.width(containerSize)

    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
        Text(
            text = if (index >= pinText.length) "" else pinText[index].toString(),
            color = digitColor,
            modifier = modifier,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
            fontSize = digitSize,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        if (type == PIN_VIEW_TYPE_UNDERLINE) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(digitColor)
                    .height(1.dp)
                    .width(containerSize)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a genius move and deserves an oscar.  

If you only need digits, its better to change `keyboardType = KeyboardType.NumberPassword` because according to https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/input/KeyboardType.Companion#Number(), the Number IME may provide inputs other than digits but it is not guaranteed.

You could change border color alpha `MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground.copy(borderAlpha.value)` to make it more apealing. Here, borderAlpha is a State which can be `0.3f` or `1f`. You can adjust to your own transparency level

Answer (score 5):

If you faced keyboard issues try the code below:

```
@Composable
fun OtpCell(
    modifier: Modifier,
    value: String,
    isCursorVisible: Boolean = false
) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val (cursorSymbol, setCursorSymbol) = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = cursorSymbol, isCursorVisible) {
        if (isCursorVisible) {
            scope.launch {
                delay(350)
                setCursorSymbol(if (cursorSymbol.isEmpty()) "|" else "")
            }
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Text(
            text = if (isCursorVisible) cursorSymbol else value,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
        )
    }
}

@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@Composable
fun PinInput(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    length: Int = 5,
    value: String = "",
    onValueChanged: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val keyboard = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = {
            if (it.length <= length) {
                if (it.all { c -> c in '0'..'9' }) {
                    onValueChanged(it)
                }
                if (it.length >= length) {
                    keyboard?.hide()
                }
            }
        },
      // Hide the text field
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(0.dp)
            .focusRequester(focusRequester),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number
        )
    )

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        repeat(length) {
            OtpCell(
                modifier = modifier
                    .size(width = 45.dp, height = 60.dp)
                    .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.large)
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.surface)
                    .clickable {
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                        keyboard?.show()
                    },
                value = value.getOrNull(it)?.toString() ?: "",
                isCursorVisible = value.length == it
            )
            if (it != length - 1) Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(8.dp))
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi, How to call this function?
can you provide some examples like what values need to pass in each parameter?

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution that uses one TextField and different code length

```
@Composable
fun RegistrationCodeInput(codeLength: Int) {
    val code = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val focusRequester = FocusRequester()
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        BasicTextField(
            value = code.value,
            onValueChange = { if (it.length <= codeLength) code.value = it },
            Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester = focusRequester),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
            decorationBox = {
                CodeInputDecoration(code.value, codeLength)
            })
    }
}

@Composable
private fun CodeInputDecoration(code: String, length: Int) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .border(
                border = BorderStroke(2.dp, color = borderColor),
                shape = Shapes.small
            )
    ) {
        Row(
        ) {
            for (i in 0 until length) {
                val text = if (i < code.length) code[i].toString() else ""
                CodeEntry(text)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun CodeEntry(text: String) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(42.dp)
            .height(42.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(text = text)
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewInput() {
    RegistrationCodeInput(4)
}
```

Comment: hi, your code is good, just one issue I am facing is that the input of individual cells is not working, like if i entered 1234 and want to change 2 with 6 so need to press clear button to first erase then write again, the expected behavior is that if I click on 2 so I must be able to delete 2

Answer (score 2):

[image: OTP Screen ScreenShot]

**First make the common TextField for OTP Screen**

```
@Composable
fun CommonOtpTextField(otp: MutableState<String>) {
    val max = 1
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = otp.value,
        singleLine = true,
        onValueChange = { if (it.length <= max) otp.value = it },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Phone),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(60.dp)
            .height(60.dp),
        maxLines = 1,
        textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    )
}
```

**And Now use above CommonTextField to make four otp Field**

```
  Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 15.dp, start = 15.dp, end = 15.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            CommonOtpTextField(otp = otpOne)
            CommonOtpTextField(otp = otpTwo)
            CommonOtpTextField(otp = otpThree)
            CommonOtpTextField(otp = otpFour)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Create OTP Viewer composable layout

**OtpView composable function :**

```kotlin
@Composable
fun OtpView(
    count: Int = 0,
    onValueChange: (value: String) -> Unit
) {

    val requesterList: ArrayList<FocusRequester> = arrayListOf()
    val textList: ArrayList<MutableState<TextFieldValue>> = arrayListOf()
    var lastIndex = -1


    for (i in 0 until count) {

        // Add string mutableStateOf variables to the input count
        textList.add(
            remember {
                mutableStateOf(
                    TextFieldValue(
                        text = "",
                        selection = TextRange(0)
                    )
                )
            }
        )
        // Add FocusRequester object to the input count
        requesterList.add(FocusRequester())
    }

    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Ltr) {
        Row {

            for (i in textList.indices) {
                InputView(
                    value = textList[i].value,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .onFocusChanged {
                            // Focus on the priority cell when click in otp viewer
                            if (it.isFocused && lastIndex != i) {
                                lastIndex = i
                                setFocus(textList, requesterList)
                            }
                        }
                        .focusRequester(requesterList[i])
                        .onKeyEvent {
                            if (it.key == Key.Backspace) {

                                // Go to previous cell after clicking backspace
                                preFocus(i, textList, requesterList)
                                onValueChange(otp(textList))

                                true
                            } else {
                                false
                            }
                        }
                ) { newValue ->
                    if (newValue.text != "" && textList[i].value.text == "") {
                        textList[i].value = TextFieldValue(
                            text = newValue.text,
                            selection = TextRange(1)
                        )
                        // Go to next cell after type one digit
                        nextFocus(textList, requesterList)
                    }
                    onValueChange(otp(textList))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun otp(textList: List<MutableState<TextFieldValue>>): String {

    var otp = ""
    for (index in textList.indices) {
        otp += textList[index].value.text
    }
    return otp
}


@Composable
fun InputView(
    modifier: Modifier,
    value: TextFieldValue,
    onValueChange: (value: TextFieldValue) -> Unit
) {


    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(8.dp)
            .width(48.dp)
            .height(48.dp)
            .border(
                width = 1.dp,
                color = Gray7,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
            ),

        ) {
        BasicTextField(
            readOnly = false,
            value = value,
            modifier = modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
            onValueChange = onValueChange,
            enabled = true,
            maxLines = 1,
            textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.h4.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onDone = null
            )
        )
    }


}

fun setFocus(
    textList: List<MutableState<TextFieldValue>>,
    requesterList: List<FocusRequester>,
) {

    var founded = -1
    for (index in textList.indices) {
        if (textList[index].value.text == "") {
            requesterList[index].requestFocus()
            founded = index
            break
        }
    }
    if (founded != -1)
        requesterList[founded].requestFocus()
    else
        requesterList[requesterList.size - 1].requestFocus()
}

fun preFocus(
    index: Int,
    textList: List<MutableState<TextFieldValue>>,
    requesterList: List<FocusRequester>,
) {

    if (index != 0 || textList[0].value.text != "")
        if (index in textList.indices && textList[index].value.text != "")
            textList[index].value = TextFieldValue(
                text = "",
                selection = TextRange(0)
            )
        else if (index in 1..textList.size - 2 || textList[index].value.text == "") {
            textList[index - 1].value = TextFieldValue(
                text = "",
                selection = TextRange(0)
            )
            requesterList[index - 1].requestFocus()
        }

}


fun nextFocus(
    textList: List<MutableState<TextFieldValue>>,
    requesterList: List<FocusRequester>,
) {

    for (index in textList.indices) {
        if (textList[index].value.text == "") {
            if (index < textList.size) {
                requesterList[index].requestFocus()
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
```

**Imports :** for the convenience of friends ;)

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.BasicTextField
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalProvider
import androidx.compose.runtime.MutableState
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.FocusRequester
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.focusRequester
import androidx.compose.ui.focus.onFocusChanged
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.key.Key
import androidx.compose.ui.input.key.key
import androidx.compose.ui.input.key.onKeyEvent
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLayoutDirection
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextRange
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.ImeAction
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.KeyboardType
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextFieldValue
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.LayoutDirection
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
```

**To use, just add the function to your screen :**

```kotlin
import ir.co.comeby.market.presentation.component.OtpView

@Composable
fun OtpScreen() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()
    ) {
         OtpView(5) {
             Log.e("value", it)
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    var text = remember {
        arrayListOf(
            mutableStateOf(""), 
            mutableStateOf(""), 
            mutableStateOf(""),
            mutableStateOf(""),
        )
    }

    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        repeat(4) { index ->
            TextField(
                value = TextFieldValue(
                    text = text[index].value,
                    selection = TextRange(text[index].value.length)
                ),
                onValueChange = { value ->
                    value?.text?.let {
                        if (text[index].value.isNotEmpty() && it.isEmpty()) {
                            text[index].value = ""
                        } else if (it.isEmpty()) {
                            focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Left)
                        } else if (it.length == 2) {
                            if (index + 1 < 4) {
                                text[index + 1].value = it.last().toString()
                            }
                            focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Right)
                        } else {
                            if (it.length <= 1) {
                                text[index].value = it
                            }
                            if (it.length == 1) {
                                focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Right)
                            }

                            if (it.isEmpty()) {
                                focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Left)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                },

                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(75.dp)
                    .onKeyEvent {
                        if (it.key == Key.Delete || it.key == Key.Backspace) {
                            if (text[index].value.isEmpty()) {
                                focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Left)
                            }
                            true
                        } else {
                            false
                        }
                    },
                singleLine = true,
            )
        }
    }
```