# how to create a code entry input style jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Im using jetpack compose and kotlin, what I need to create a textinput for a sms code that looks like the one on the image, it should just accept 5 numbers,  the thing is that I dont know how to make it look like this, that one number per line, tried to do 5 separate inputs but its not that smooth, is therea way to do this with only one text input?
[image]

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69270834/how-to-create-a-otp-layout-in-android-compose/69271962#69271962

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use decorationBox field in BasicTextField to decorate the text field as below

```
BasicTextField(

    value = "",
    singleLine = true,
    onValueChange = {
       
    },
    enabled = true,
    keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
    decorationBox = {
        Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            repeat(length) { index ->
                CharView(
                    index = index,
                    text = textValue,
                    modifier = Modifier
                )
            }
        }
    }
)

@Composable
fun CharView(){
// compose code to show one underline in purple color
}
```

Comment: how do to it when each number in separate rectangle rounded shape?