# OTP in Jetpack Compose - Android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to build a OTP input like this:

[image: Image here]

I don't have ANY ideia how to do this.
Can you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69270834/how-to-create-a-otp-layout-in-android-compose/69271962#69271962

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It can be easily implemented with BasicTextField's decorationBox:

```
@Composable
fun RegistrationCodeInput(codeLength: Int, initialCode: String, onTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
    val code = remember(initialCode) {
        mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(initialCode, TextRange(initialCode.length)))
    }
    val focusRequester = FocusRequester()
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        BasicTextField(
            value = code.value,
            onValueChange = { onTextChanged(it.text) },
            modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester = focusRequester),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
            decorationBox = {
                CodeInputDecoration(code.value.text, codeLength)
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun CodeInputDecoration(code: String, length: Int) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier) {
        Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
            for (i in 0 until length) {
                val text = if (i < code.length) code[i].toString() else ""
                CodeEntry(text)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun CodeEntry(text: String) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
            .width(35.dp)
            .height(55.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        val color = animateColorAsState(
            targetValue = if (text.isEmpty()) Color.Gray.copy(alpha = .8f)
            else Color.Blue.copy(.8f)
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
            text = text,
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
        )
        Box(
            Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                .padding(start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
                .height(2.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color.value)
        )
    }
}
```

## Usage:

```
val otp = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

RegistrationCodeInput(
    codeLength = 6,
    initialCode = otp.value,
    onTextChanged = { otp.value = it }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! With all the examples out there, this is the one it works best for me. I had a problem with autocompleting the OTP, probably something related to the focusRequester, which was not allowing me to delete a filled OTP. With this example everything works perfectly. Thanks a lot.